# PHP MySQL insert into table database with $_GET method using Codeigniter-3 + Dropzone-4.1

Tags: php, mysql, css, codeigniter-3

Working on  CodeIgniter 3, and encountering issue on "id_case". it says undefined index: id_case.

when i click a link in **index.php**

```
<?php echo "<td><a href='/ci_dropzone/?id_case=".$row['id_case']."'>Upload File To This ID</a></td>";?>
```

and then i use codeigniter 3 + Dropzone-4.1, 
in  the file says **upload.php** in controller folder there are :

```
<?php require 'conn.php'; <== i add this linker
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Gambar extends CI_Controller {
    private $datauser;
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('url','file'));
    }

    function index(){
        $data['js'] = base_url('assets/js');
        $data['css'] = base_url('assets/css');
        $data['img'] = base_url('assets/images');

        $this->load->view('gambar', $data);
    }

    function gambar_upload() {

        if (!empty($_FILES)) {
            $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
            $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
            $filelink = $_GET['id_case']; <== i add this line
            $targetPath = './assets/uploads/';
            $targetFile = $targetPath . $fileName ;

            move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);

            $this->db->insert('uploadtable', array( 'idlink' => $filelink, 'nama' => $fileName, 'tipe' => $fileType, 'ukuran' => $fileSize));
        }
    }
}?>
```

I try hard how to use function **$_GET** to get the **id_case** number so that iam able to use the id_case number automatically without tag `<form>` and submit order to insert to the database **uploadtable** in the **idlink** table column. the error shown like this :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: id_case
>
> Filename: controllers/upload.php
>
> Line Number: 32
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: E:\controlX\htdocs\ci-dropzone\application\controllers\upload.php
>   Line: 32
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: E:\controlX\htdocs\ci-dropzone\index.php
>   Line: 294
>   Function: require_once
>   A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1048
>
> Column 'idlink' cannot be null
>
> INSERT INTO `uploadtable` (`idlink`, `nama`, `tipe`, `ukuran`) VALUES (NULL, '10000000000257660_1920x1080.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 1257381)
>
> Filename: E:/controlX/htdocs/ci-dropzone/application/controllers/upload.php
>
> Line Number: 38

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try in constructor?

Such as;

```
function __construct() {
    $this->case_id = isset($_GET['case_id']) ? $_GET['case_id'] : null;
}
```

This should be work.